# Kendo Filterable Cell Multiple Contains

Tags: filter, kendo-ui

Is it possible to search for both "Doe" and "Smith" with modifications to the below?  Is there a way to make it so that the search box accepts two values?

i.e. Doe|Smith or Doe,Smith as the search string

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      columns: [
          { field: "name", filterable: { cell: { operator: "contains", showOperators: false } } },
          { field: "age", filterable: { cell: { operator: "contains", showOperators: false } } }
      ],
      filterable: { mode: "row"},
      dataSource: {
       data: [
        { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
        { id: 2, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
        { id: 3, name: "Bill Smith", age: 40 },
        { id: 4, name: "Tom Jones", age: 99 }
       ],
       schema:{
        model: {
         id: "id",
         fields: {
           age: { type: "number"}
         }
        }
       }
      }
  });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: An alternative to using the the default search box is to instead use the [columns.filterable.multi](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.filterable.multi) functionality.  This will allow you to at least select multiple values.

Comment: Additionally, without configuring cell filterability, there's [columns.filterable.extra](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.filterable.extra)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the javascript declaration of a kendo grid but with an MVC declaration,by simply adding

```
.Filterable()
```

You can filter against two values with and `AND` or an `OR`.